# search feature does not search in metadata?

Tags: search, managed-metadata

I made a test library with 3 different columns of metadata
1) from managed metadata
2) from a lookup in a separate list
3) as a choice column

I was under the impression that every term/element in any of those columns was considered for the search, instead it isn't.

Is there anything that needs configuring?

I am on sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

So search should pick up these columns as long as there is data in the columns, if there is no data in the columns then search ignores it. To see if search is actually picking up the column go to **site settings -> search schema** then in the **Managed property** textbox enter in the site column name to see if it is in search. Also since this is SharePoint Online it usually takes 5 -15 minutes before it'll show up in search, but sometimes it takes hours .... good times :)